# Orbeon integration with Play! Framework?

Tags: playframework, orbeon

I am very curious if someone has tried to integrate Play! Framework with [orbeon](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/packaging-and-deployment) ?

Or do you know if this integration is possible?

[Here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial) is a simple HelloWorld application in orbeon. As you see there is xhtml code while in Play! we have html...

I'd really appreciate a little feedback on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon is based on the servlet spec and jsp's, so you can run it on every servlet container (tomcat, etc.) **but not in play**.

Recently, someone has posted a FormEE plugin on the play mailinglist - take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it would be a case of porting the org.orbeon.oxf.fr.embedding.servlet.* classes (from the main source tree) to use a Play filter (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters​)

To preserve session state, it might be necessary to run the Play application within the same servlet container as the Orbeon Form runner war, in which case you would need the Play 2 war plugin (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992202/116509)

Comment: To produce the original embedded HTML should be very simple: it is really just about having an OutputStream available. However as you noticed the embedding also requires a servlet filter, which intercepts incoming Ajax requests and CSS/JS, and the equivalent should be provided for Play. There should be no need to share the same servlet container.