# How to deploy a Scala Play framework API using the SBT native packager

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, web-deployment, typesafe-activator, sbt-native-packager

I created a web API based on the Scala Play framework 2. In the past I generated *war* files using a SBT plugin in order to deploy in production using Tomcat. It is now possible to build native package from Play project using the SBT native packager plugin. I used it to generate a debian package from my web app.

However, I don't understand how it works. I could generate and install the debian package and start the daemon, but my API seems not listening request.

In the first case, Tomcat hosts the war file which contains the Play app and manages the HTTP connection. I have the feeling that there are missing parts in my debian package in order to work properly like the *war* file under Tomcat.

The question is, how can I use the native packager plugin to deploy a standalone HTTP API? What is responsible to handle HTTP connection? What is missing in my project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play applications run using their own light weight http server.

To build a standalone project issue

```
sbt dist
```

or if your using activator

```
activator dist
```

This makes a directory **target/universal/your-app.zip**

If you unzip the contents you will find a standalone application structure

```
/bin
/lib
/conf
/share
```

under which you can find shellscripts that launch the server

```
bin/your-app
bin/your-app.bat (windows)
```

The distribution to a war file appears to have been removed from play. Similar question asked here:
[Deploy play as a war file into a servlet container, even if it uses JPA heavily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985783/deploy-play-as-a-war-file-into-a-servlet-container-even-if-it-uses-jpa-heavily)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it also possible to build a standalone app packaged in a debian package?

Comment: Native packager only builds standalone dists. However you need to configure play a bit if you want to deploy it. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/play.html also make sure you are using the right port and the wpp is actually running